# Why swappiness in AWS EC2 is 60 although there is no swap space by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, swap

I used the AMI Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS (HVM), SSD Volume Type.

By default, there is no SWAP space.

swappiness is the default value 60.

My question is, if there is no SWAP space by default, should we also set swappiness to 0?

Is it because there is no difference between **60** and **0** when there is no SWAP space?

Comment: As you say 60 is the default. Why bother changing it when there is no swap anyway?

Comment: @Rodney I'm not sure if it's better to set to 0.